# Implementation of Counting Sort in Python

Tags: python-2.7, sorting

I'm trying this [HackerRank problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/countingsort4). So far, I've ended up with this code :

```
n = int(raw_input())
ar = []

for i in xrange(n):
    ar.append(raw_input().split())

output = [0] * 1000000
count = [0] * 100

for a in ar:    
    count[int(a[0])] += 1

total = 0

for a in xrange(100):
    old = count[a]
    count[a] = total
    total += old

for a in ar:
    if ar.index(a) < n/2:
        output[count[int(a[0])]] = '-'
    else:
        output[count[int(a[0])]] = a[1]
    count[int(a[0])] += 1

for o in output:
    if type(o) != str:
        break
    else:
        print o,
```

Out of 5 test cases, it only passed one. 2 were timed out because of high running time, but that's not my priority now. My priority is passing the other 2 test cases which completely failed. I can't figure where I could have gone wrong. I know I can probably make my code more efficient, but for now, I'm focusing on just getting the right output.

Comment: I can only run one test case without signing up; but for performance: a) do all the `int()` conversions once at the start - while loading the data. Split it, convert to `int()` and then do `ar.append`. b) Same for replacing the first half with dashes, don't use `output[count[int(a[0` when know the first half right at the very top when loading them into the array. Load a dash instead for the first half. c) No need to make `output` that big, make it `[0] * n` instead - lower memory use. d) Maybe skip the `type(o)` test on every output and just print o.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect all your issues (both time and correctness) come from using `ar.index(a)` to check if a value is in the first half of the input list.

That line will always be very slow all the time (searching the list takes O(N) time), and it will give the wrong answer if there are two identical lines, one in the first half of the input and one in the second half. Instead, use `enumerate` to get the index as you are iterating over the list:

```
for i, a in enumerate(ar):
    if i < n/2:
        output[count[int(a[0])]] = '-'
    else:
        output[count[int(a[0])]] = a[1]
    count[int(a[0])] += 1
```

You can probably improve several other things (like making `output` length `n`, or converting each key to an `int` just once), but getting rid of the calls to `list.index()` is probably the most important fix.

Comment: Thank you! The `enumerate()` did do the trick. I also made `output` length `n`.